# Image Recongition with pyautogui: How do I search for multiple areas at once?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using python to search for images and I can do that with one area but how can I adapt this code for multiple areas?

```
found_image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image)
if found_image !=None:
    pyautogui.click(found_image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to stack! PIL has a flag for regions literally called region. If you specify where you regions are top left x and y and bottom right x and y you can them loop through the regions with `for region_name, region in regions.items():` and then do *something* if your image is found in any of the regions.

```
regions = {
"Top left": (top, left, bottom, right),
"Bottom left": (top, left, bottom, right),
"Top right": (top, left, bottom, right),
"Bottom right": (top, left, bottom, right)
}

for region_name, region in regions.items():
    found_image = py.locateOnScreen(image, region=region)
    if found_image != None:
        print(f"Clicked found_image in {region_name} region.")
        py.click(found_image )
```

Comment: that seems to have worked straight away, thank you!

Comment: no worries! I have asked some similar questions recently, if you check my profile and look under questions some of it might be of use!

Comment: I'll have a look now, thanks!